# Has anyone succeeded to port SpeakHere for ARC?

Tags: c++, ios, ios5, compilation, xcode4.2

My compiler reported a lot of error when I were trying to integrate record/play code from SpeakHere.
I have followed suggestions to use a .mm file to include cpp include file, the only exception is I am using iOS 5 with ARC enabled.

My code is:

```
//header file
#import "AQPlayer.h"
#import "AQRecorder.h"

@interface MyClass : NSObject {

UIButton *record;
UIButton *cancel;
UIButton *stop;
UIButton *play;

//
AQPlayer*                   player;
AQRecorder*                 recorder;
BOOL                        playbackWasInterrupted;
BOOL                        playbackWasPaused;

CFStringRef                 recordFilePath; 
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet DrawerAudioNote *dnote;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *record;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *cancel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *stop;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *play;

- (IBAction) doRecord:(id)sender;
- (IBAction) doStop:(id)sender;
- (IBAction) doCancel:(id)sender;
- (IBAction) doPlay:(id)sender;

//
@property (readonly)            AQPlayer            *player;
@property (readonly)            AQRecorder          *recorder;

//.mm file (no compile error)
@import "MyClass.h"
@implementation MyClass

@synthesize record, cancel, stop, play;
@synthesize playbackWasInterrupted;
@synthesize player, recorder;

//CAXException.h (an example cpp file with compile errors)
......
class CAX4CCString { 
//ERROR: Expect ';' after top level declarator
//ERROR: Unknown type name; do you mean 'Class'?
public:
    CAX4CCString(OSStatus error) {
        // see if it appears to be a 4-char-code
        char *str = mStr;
        *(UInt32 *)(str + 1) = CFSwapInt32HostToBig(error);
        if (isprint(str[1]) && isprint(str[2]) && isprint(str[3]) && isprint(str[4])) {         
            str[0] = str[5] = '\'';
            str[6] = '\0';
        } else if (error > -200000 && error < 200000)
            // no, format it as an integer
            sprintf(str, "%d", (int)error);
        else
            sprintf(str, "0x%x", (int)error);
    }
    const char *get() const { return mStr; }
    operator const char *() const { return mStr; }
private:
    char mStr[16];
};
```

By compilation errors in class 'CAX4CCString', the compiler seems does not understand he is working on CPP file. 
I know I would have missed something in somewhere, anyone can point out?

Thanks in advance,

Sean

Comment: Even if someone has ported SpeakHere to iOS 5 with ARC enabled, they can't currently say so for contractual reasons. It might be worth asking again when the tools are out of NDA.

Answer (score 2):

Why not disable ARC for specific files? Your project remains with ARC, except the problematic files.  Add `-fno-objc-arc` to the compiler flags for the files you don't want with ARC. In Xcode, you can do this under your target -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring the C++ class

```
class CAX4CCString {
```

inside of the Objective-C class `MyClass`. I fear this is not supported by Objective-C.

What I think you could so is declare `CAX4CCString` in the global scope and then instantiate and use it from your Objective-C class:

```
//.mm file

class CAX4CCString { 
   ....
};


@implementation MyClass

@synthesize record, cancel, stop, play;
@synthesize playbackWasInterrupted;
@synthesize player, recorder;
...
   <do something with CAX4CCString>
@end
```